# Combine htaccess rewrite and get

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to make url like this 
`http://example.com/search?word=something`.
But when I rewrite with htaccess I can't get the `$_GET["word"]`.

My htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^search\?word=([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=search&word=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What are you rewriting too? That URL should work. Try `var_dump($_GET);` if it isn't working to see whats in there.

Comment: my htaccess is like this RewriteRule ^search\?word=([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=search&word=$1 [L]

Comment: then page exception 404 not found

Comment: QSA or QSD flag could possibly help: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa.

Comment: You can have this rule: `RewriteRule ^search$ /index.php?page=search [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Benno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575047/benno). I solve the problem with adding QSA flag to RewriteRule.